# Heranças de CSS

Tags: css

É possível herda uma classe de um css para outro css?
Ex:

```
    .div1{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #088fad 20%, #00d5ff 100%);

    }
```

queria que esta div1 herdasse a classe `col-md-12` para que não seja necessária adiciona-la a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer que tudo que for `div1` automaticamente se comporte como `col-md12`, só com CSS, sem por no HTML não tem uma maneira óbvia sem repetir as instruções.

O que dá pra fazer é usar ferramentas como [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), que tem os *mixins* que fazem composição de várias classes, mas só funcionam se ele tiver acesso aos arquivos originais para produzir um resultado.

Agora, se puder ajustar o HTML, pode acrescentar várias classes num mesmo elemento separando com espaços:

```
<div class="col-md12 div1 outrasclasses">
```

Aí, se quer que uma DIV funcione só com determinada combinação, pode usar mais de uma classe na definição das características:

```
.col-md12.div1{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #088fad 20%, #00d5ff 100%);

}
```

Veja abaixo que o fundo vermelho só atua nos casos em que as duas classes estão definidas, mas o `bold` funciona em ambas com classe `div1`.

```css
.div1{
  font-weight:bold;
}

.col-md12.div1{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">DIV A</div>
<div class="col-md12">DIV B</div>
<div class="col-md12 div1">DIV C</div>
```

Comment: Desta maneira eu já sabia, eu pensei que por exemplo tivesse um código com várias divs com a classe col-md-12 por exemplo, é quisesse que todas herdade o atributo da div1. Mas obrigado @Bacco

Comment: @FabioSouza mas nesse caso, nada impede de você colocar uma definição .col-md-12 no seu CSS também. Aí vão valer as coisas dos dois.